# Как проверить разрядность системы?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Имея данный алгоритм, почему-то большую часть показывает `x32`. У меня стоит `x64`

---

```
private static bool Is64Bit()
{
    return IntPtr.Size == 8;
}

public static string CheckOS()
{
    if (Is64Bit())
        return "x64";
    else
        return "x32";
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsWow64Process([In] IntPtr hProcess, out bool lpSystemInfo);
```

---

Как нормально проверить на всех осях разрядность?

Comment: Как насчёт [Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Решил проблему по другому) Теперь всё работает как надо) Взял за основу [OSVersionInfo](http://sources.ru/csharp/OSVersionInfo.html)

Comment: @Nikita: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, я подумал, возможно автору принципиально использовать вызовы WinAPI для этой задачи. Но ок, сейчас перенесу.

Comment: Хорошо Сделаем как ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```
internal class OSCheckBit
{
    private static bool Is32BitProcessOn64BitProcessor()
    {
        IsWow64ProcessDelegate fnDelegate = GetIsWow64ProcessDelegate();
        if (fnDelegate == null)
            return false;
        bool isWow64;
        bool retVal = fnDelegate.Invoke(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out isWow64);
        if (retVal == false)
            return false;
        return isWow64;
    }
    private static IsWow64ProcessDelegate GetIsWow64ProcessDelegate()
    {
        IntPtr handle = LoadLibrary("kernel32");
        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr fnPtr = GetProcAddress(handle, "IsWow64Process");
            if (fnPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                return (IsWow64ProcessDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer((IntPtr)fnPtr, typeof(IsWow64ProcessDelegate));
        }
        return null;
    }
    public enum SoftwareArchitecture
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        x32 = 1,
        x64 = 2
    }
    static public SoftwareArchitecture OSBits
    {
        get
        {
            SoftwareArchitecture osbits = SoftwareArchitecture.Unknown;

            switch (IntPtr.Size * 8)
            {
                case 64: osbits = SoftwareArchitecture.x64; break;
                case 32: if (Is32BitProcessOn64BitProcessor())
                             osbits = SoftwareArchitecture.x64;
                    else
                        osbits = SoftwareArchitecture.x32;
                    break;
                default:
                    osbits = SoftwareArchitecture.Unknown;
                    break;
            }

            return osbits;
        }
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public extern static IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libraryName);
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public extern static IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hwnd, string procedureName);
    private delegate bool IsWow64ProcessDelegate([In] IntPtr handle, [Out] out bool isWow64Process);
```

Вызов:  `Console.WriteLine($"Версия Вашей ОС: {OSCheckBit.OSBits}");`

Answer (score 4):

Начиная с 4 версии фреймворка существует простой способ проверить разрядность ОС, используя статический класс `Environment` и его свойство [`Is64BitOperatingSystem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem?view=netframework-4.7#System_Environment_Is64BitOperatingSystem):

```
using System;

static string GetOSBit()
{
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        return "x64";
    else
        return "x32";
}
```

`Console.WriteLine(GetOSBit());`